# Apple's Blue Warning Bar overlaps the NavBar of my Navigation Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a view setup inside a UINavigationController. The Blue Warning Bar displays over the top of the NavigationController's NavBar. In another part of my project I have another UINavigationController setup inside a UITabController. The NavBar allows enough room for the Blue Warning Bar to display without an overlay.

What am I missing? How can I prevent the Blue Bar from overlaying the NavBar?
[Blue Bar of Shame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SL7i.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Here is what was actually happening:

I have a View Controller inside a Navigation Controller. This View Controller contains a list of “Appointments”. When the user taps on an “Appointment” the application segues to a detail view that uses a Tab Bar Controller with five tabs, each of which have their own Navigation Controller. The first tab has an address field that allows the user to launch a Navigation App (Apple Maps, Google Maps or Waze) by tapping on it.

After opening the Navigation App, if the user returns to my application while the navigation app is still open and they did not provide the proper permission to suppress the Blue Bar of Shame, then the Blue Bar of Shame is displayed above my Navigation Bar, as it should be. If they then tap the back button to dismiss the Tab Bar Controller and return to the original Navigation Controller, the Blue Bar of Shame is overlaid on top of the Navigation Bar.

I'm not sure if this is a bug with UIKit or not.

What I did to work around this:

I changed the manner in which an Appointment List selection opens the selected Appointment's Detail. I was using a simple segue. For some reason when navigating back to the Appointment List view from the Appointment Detail, the Appointment List view's Navigation Bar was not accounting for the expanded status bar when the Blue Bar of Shame was displayed. I ended up completely replacing the rootView, which was displaying the Appointment List, with the Appointment Detail Tab Bar Controller. When transitioning back, I do the same thing in reverse - replace the Appointment Detail with the Appointment List; this seems to have alleviated the rendering problem.

I then created an extension for UIWindow to emulate the default navigation style transition during the rootView replacements.